# What letters (A-Z) have Chinese counterparts?

Tags: translation

Some letters (A-Z) have Chinese character counterparts. For instance:

- X = 叉
- U = 优

What other examples of this phenomenon are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A(ei)诶；
B(bi)必、币、毕、闭、碧；
C(sei)；
D(di)弟、地、第、帝；
E(yi)易、意、义、驿、亿；
F(ai fu)爱抚、爱付；
G；
H(ei chi)诶吃；
I(ai)爱；
J(zhei)；
K(kei)尅、剋；
L(ai lou)爱楼、(ai ou)爱偶；
M(ai mu)爱木；
N(en)嗯、恩；
O(ou)偶、欧；
P(pi)皮、屁；
Q(kiu)；
R(er)二；
S(ai si)艾斯；
T(ti)题、体、替、涕；
U(you)尤、右、又、由、友、邮、优；
V(wei)位、味、喂；
W(da bo you)打波右、(da bu liu)达不流(changlish)；
X(ai ke si )爱克思；
Y(wai)外、歪；
Z；

Comment: how is Z read aloud?

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a page entitled, [Chinese respelling of the English alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_respelling_of_the_English_alphabet)

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

> In the case of "U = 优", 优 is a sound-alike loan word of "U".

Similarly:

"i" = "愛" /Ài/ (as in "愛鳳/ iPhone") - *愛 is the loan word for "i"*

"嗑" /Kē/ = "k" (as in "嗑毒品/ K毒品") - *k is the loan word for "嗑"*

Much like:

Bus - 巴士

Taxi - 的士

> In the case of "X = 叉", "叉" is a graphical representation of the alphabet "X".

"X" looked like a "交叉" (cross), therefore, people nicknamed "X" as "叉"

Comment: "i" = "愛" works, but "嗑" = "k" is going the wrong direction. K9 units aren't going to be rendered as 嗑久.